# Need Options Value to work on my Code

Tags: php, show-hide

Hello i have a php site and i trying to make an element as optional value but i have no ideas how it works.

See 1st Image 1 
![1st Image][1]
it is shown on all pages but i want to make it optional to show and hide

here is the code i have added a code add page section

See 2nd Image 
 
[image: 2nd Image]

Code is

```
<label for="name-in" class="col-md-3 label-heading">Color Name</label>  
<div class="col-md-9">
        <select name="is_colorname" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
            <option value="0">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Value `Yes` is Show Color Text, `No` is Hidden

Now This Code Need to Show and hide

```
    <?php if (!$is_colorname) : ?><?php if(!empty($bstf)) { echo $bstf; } echo '</p><br><br>'; ?>
    <p class="card-title center-align comic wishesed">
    <?php if($wish!="love" ) { 
        if($wish=="bestf" ) { 
            if(!$is_doublename) {?>
                <span class="deep-orange-text text-darken-2">W</span>
                <span class="green-text text-accent-4">e &nbsp;</span>
                <span class="blue-text text-lighten-1">A</span>
                <span class=" teal-text text-accent-3">r</span>
                <span class="red-text text-accent-3">e</span>
            <?php }
            else{
                echo '
                    <span class="orange-text darken-1">W</span>
                    <span class="green-text text-accent-4">i</span>
                    <span class="lime-text">s</span>
                    <span class="teal-text text-accent-3">h</span>
                    <span class="blue-grey-text lighten-5">i</span>
                    <span class="lime-text">n</span>
                    <span class="orange-text text-accent-3">g &nbsp;</span>
                <span class="lime-text">Y</span>
                    <span class="teal-text text-accent-3">o</span>
                    <span class="lime-text text-accent-3">u</span>';
                    }
        } else if($wish=="friend" || $wish=="rakhi" ) { 
            if(!$is_doublename) {
                echo '
                            <span class="orange-text darken-1">W</span>
                            <span class="green-text text-accent-4">i</span>
                            <span class="lime-text">s</span>
                            <span class="teal-text text-accent-3">h</span>
                            <span class="blue-grey-text lighten-5">i</span>
                            <span class="lime-text">n</span>
                            <span class="orange-text text-accent-3">g &nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="lime-text">Y</span>
                            <span class="teal-text text-accent-3">o</span>
                            <span class="lime-text text-accent-3">u</span>';
                    }
                    else{
                        echo '
                <span class="deep-orange-text text-darken-2">W</span>
                <span class="green-text text-accent-4">e &nbsp;</span>
                <span class="blue-text text-lighten-1">A</span>
                <span class=" teal-text text-accent-3">r</span>
                <span class="red-text text-accent-3">e</span>
                    ';
                }
    } else {  
        if(!$is_doublename) {?>
            <span class="deep-orange-text text-darken-2">W</span>
            <span class="green-text text-accent-4">i</span>
            <span class="blue-text text-lighten-1">s</span>
            <span class=" teal-text text-accent-3">h</span>
            <span class="red-text text-accent-3">i</span>
            <span class="lime-text">n</span>
            <span class="orange-text text-accent-3">g &nbsp;</span>
            <span class="lime-text">Y</span>
            <span class=" blue-text text-darken-1">o</span>
            <span class="lime-text text-accent-3">u</span>
        <?php }
        else { ?>
            <span class="deep-orange-text text-darken-2">W</span>
            <span class="green-text text-accent-4">e &nbsp;</span>
            <span class="blue-text text-lighten-1">A</span>
            <span class=" teal-text text-accent-3">r</span>
            <span class="red-text text-accent-3">e</span>
        <?php }
    } 
} ?><?php endif ?>;
```

Website Link :

How can i that colorful text to show and hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your request variable that represents the 'color name' field, after submiting the form, and render or not the element, like you're already doing with `$is_doublename`

The code will be something like this:

```
<?php if (!$is_colorname) : ?>
    // Html code to print the name
<?php endif ?>;
```

Comment: Hello Sir Thanks for Your Answer But I want to Hide Content on "No" Value and It's By default Show on all Pages Which are checked as Yes But I want to Hidden It  I have Fewer Ideas about it This code not Written by me so Can u tell me briefly..... Will be appreciated Your Valuable Time... Check Code Its Edited Is it Right place to put your given code.......